# Button is not getting enabled on text input in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In an Instagram MERN project, I've created Comment box for each users. Post button is disabled on startup and enabled when text is inputted, but, here the button is disabled even after text input which prevents it from submitting. Following is the code reference

Home.js

```
const Home = () => {
        
        const [newText, setNewText] = useState([])

        const onChange = e => {
              const { value } = e.target;
              setNewText(value);
         };
                    
        const makeComment = (text,postId)=>{
        fetch('/comment',{
            method:"put",
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json",
                "Authorization":"Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("jwt")
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                postId,
                text
            })
        }).then(res=>res.json())
        .then(result=>{
            console.log(result)
            const newData = data.map(item=>{
              if(item._id==result._id){
                  return {...item,comments: result.comments}
              }else{
                  return item
              }
           })
          setData(newData)
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
  }

return (
       {
                 return (
          <form onSubmit={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); makeComment(e.target[0].value, item._id)}}>
            <input type="text" value={newText[item._id]} onChange={onChange} placeholder="add a comment/>
            <button type="submit" disabled={!newText[item._id]}>Post</button>
          </form>
                        )
       }
}
```

[image]

See the image above. Here you can see the button is not enabled and text is prevented from submitting. What wold be the better solution?

Comment: where are you rendering the list and where did you define `data` state?

Comment: console.log(newText, newText[item._id]) to see if its undefined or true or false firstly

Comment: @Iam Yes I'am getting undefined

Comment: When consoled I'am getting text for newText and undefined for newText[item._id]

Comment: Where is the onChange function? Where do you call setNewText?

Comment: I've added onChange function, edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working solution: [https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-thunder-bgol9](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-thunder-bgol9?file=/src/App.js)

The button is disabled because newText[item._id] is false, or undefined. In your onChange handler, you need to set newText[item._id] to be true, or rather to have the value of the input.

```
const item = { _id: 1, name: "name" };

const [newText, setNewText] = React.useState([]);
const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

const onChange = (e, id) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const changedText = newText;
    changedText[item._id] = value;
    setNewText(changedText);

    setCounter(counter + 1);
};
```

Where input is:

```
   <input
      type="text"
      value={newText[item._id] ? newText[item._id] : ""}
      onChange={(e) => {
        onChange(e, item._id);
      }}
      placeholder="add a comment"
    />
```

Some notes to this code:

- You had a typo in your JSX, missing ". Also, you didn't provide item
  variable, so I added it as a constant. You will need to have it in
  your component (probably from the props).
- As you are having a controlled input, but initially the newText is an
  empty array, you should check whether newText[item._id] is empty. If
  it has value, show the value, if it is empty, show the empty string.
- Your onChange function should get item._id as a parameter, so it
  knows which item is being edited.
- As you store the input in an array, as one array item, updating this
  array won't trigger component's rerender, because at
  ShouldComponentUpdate, React is doing only shallow comparison of it's
  state variables. For this, you need to "hack" it, by also setStating
  some other variable, which will trigger the rerender of the
  component, and thus updating of your input with current value.

Generally, what you are doing here is not a good architecture. You shouldn't store your input's value in an array, since you don't have many inputs. Store it only in normal string variable. Then, when you are submitting it, add this variable to your array of items.

Comment: Your solution is working no doubt, but, when I use your code in my project is not working...

Comment: Only small change is expected... see if you can, I want to clear the text on submit

Comment: Can you make changes in your codesandbox?

Comment: Congrats. I changed that, see line 24. Basically it will again set the state of that array's item to be empty string.

Comment: Bravo! you are awesome thanks.... Finally I've done with the project

Comment: I want to increase your points... but, unable to do since, I need 15 points to do so... Well thanks very much